# Why to store date as timestamps?

Tags: date, timestamp

I am creating a node app with mongo and trying to store createdOn field. I have two options, either go with the ISO date format("YYYY-MMM-DDThh:mm:ss.zzz") or use timestamp. My users will be mostly in India but my server is in Oregon USA, and all computation will be done over there. Just wanted your thoughts on which one to use and why?Could not find a nice blog post searching this. I hope the smart people who have already done this would help a fellow newbie out.

What am I already doing?
I am saving the date in the date time format,using momentTimeZone by `Asia/Kolkata`  time and extracting it out. It's very painful and I have to remember that every time I write anything related to date I have to first convert it into IST and then proceed with any ops. Hence require your suggestion, whether to continue like this or try timestamp approach

Comment: You should always use UTC, until you're ready to display a final result.

Comment: So no time stamp?

Comment: You should use a timestamp with a value in UTC.

Comment: Okay... But why timestamp? What advantage do they provide over storing as DateTime

Comment: What do you mean by "DateTime"? Strings don't let you do any kind of logic or manipulation,

Comment: Mongo stores date in an ISO-8601 date format. Which is not string data type

Comment: If you have an actual datetime type (which is not string), you should certainly use that (still with UTC).  That's now what you said in the question.